# 4' flush-mount LED light won't dim

Tags: led

I have purchased two identical 4' flush mount LED lights and two identical dimmer switches.  The first set I installed in the master bathroom works perfectly.  The dimmer switch goes from very low light to very bright like just as it should.  The second set in the upstairs bathroom will not dim at all.  I have replaced both the light and the switch now and it still will not dim.  What do I do to make the second bathroom work like the first bathroom?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What make/model are the lights and dimmers? Are the dimmers LED-compatible? Does the second set turn off? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What happens if you swap the non-dimming light into the fixture where dimming works?  Ditto the switches.  Also,  do both switches have proper grounding in their boxes?

Comment: In situations where "two exact things don't work the same" they are either not exactly the same somehow, or something is broken.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.  Daniel, yes, the non-dimming lights will turn off.  Carl - I have not tried switching the switches yet, but I will give that a try and see if there is any progress.  JPhi - Both lights are the 4' arctic flush mount and on the box, it calls for C & L dimmer switches - the box says they are compatible.  The second time around I asked the people at home depot to be sure I was reading the information correctly, and both people I spoke to there confirmed I was purchasing compatible items.

Comment: What make and model are the dimmers and LED bulbs in question?

Comment: Hi ThreePhaseEel -- The lights are Hampton Bay Arctic Glacier White Small LED Flush Mount Purchased from Home Depot…  website for the light is https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Arctic-Glacier-White-Small-LED-Flush-Mount-HBL1143A-06/206638018?MERCH=REC-_-PLP_Search-_-206638013;202519232;-_-206638018-_-N

Comment: And the dimmer switches are Lutron Toggler C.L Dimmer Switch for Dimmable LED, Halogen and Incandescent Bulbs, Single-Pole or 3-Way, White which are listed on the box for the lights and purchased at Home Depot and the website for them is:  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Toggler-C-L-Dimmer-Switch-for-Dimmable-LED-Halogen-and-Incandescent-Bulbs-Single-Pole-or-3-Way-White-TGCL-153PH-WH/202746671

Answer (score 1):

Test the working dimmer on the light that won't dim...  And test the non working dimmer on the light that you know will dim... to verify its not a bad dimmer or fixture.

Also try swapping the wires on the dimmer....  some dimmers require the hot to connect to a certain pole and the switch leg to connect to a certain pole.  Some dimmers also have an optional third wire for a three way switch configuration, be sure you aren't using that one.